# Validating file records shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a file with content as follows and want to validate the content as

1.I have entries of **rec$NUM** and this field should be repeated 7 times only.
for example I have rec1.any_attribute this rec1 should come only 7 times in whole file.

2.I need validating script for this.
If records for **rec$NUM** are **less than 7 or Greater than 7 script should report that record.**

FILE IS AS FOLLOWS :::

```
rec1:sourcefile.name=

rec1:mapfile.name=

rec1:outputfile.name=

rec1:logfile.name=

rec1:sourcefile.nodename_col=

rec1:sourcefle.snmpnode_col=

rec1:mapfile.enc=

rec2:sourcefile.name=abc

rec2:mapfile.name=

rec2:outputfile.name=

rec2:logfile.name=

rec2:sourcefile.nodename_col=

rec2:sourcefle.snmpnode_col=

rec2:mapfile.enc=

rec3:sourcefile.name=abc

rec3:mapfile.name=

rec3:outputfile.name=

rec3:logfile.name=

rec3:sourcefile.nodename_col=

rec3:sourcefle.snmpnode_col=

rec3:mapfile.enc=
```

Please Help

Thanks in Advance... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `awk`:

```
awk -F: '/^rec/{a[$1]++}END{for(t in a){if(a[t]!=7){print "Some error for record: " t}}}' test.rc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '^rec1' file.txt | wc -l
grep '^rec2' file.txt | wc -l 
grep '^rec3' file.txt | wc -l
```

All above should return 7.

Comment: Sorry but if I have 1000 records in a file how I will do for every rec

Answer (score 0):

The commands:

```
grep rec file2.txt | cut -d':' -f1 | uniq  -c | egrep -v '^ *7'
```

will success if file follows your rules, fails (and returns the failing record) if it doesn't.

(replace "uniq -c" by "sort -u" if record numbers can be mixed).